# Copy paste based on incrementing criteria

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, paste

I need help with how to code this. I'm sorry if i offended anybody. I don't understand how this works...I need help with copy pasting.

The details are as such:

1) Look for string (Sheet1!**L5**) in sheet2(F:F).....|   c  1 |
2) if found string (Sheet1!**L5**) copy that row........|   y ..   |
3) Paste in (Sheet6) **a2**                           ......................................|   c ..   |
4) else                                           ................................................................|   l....    |
5) Paste 111 in (Sheet6) **a2**                      .............................. |   e...    |

2.1)  Look for string (Sheet1!**L6**) in sheet2(F:F)     . |   c  2 |
2.2)  if found string (Sheet1!**L6**) copy that row      .....|   y  ..  |
2.3)  Paste in (Sheet6) **a3**                           ....................................|   c    ...|
2.4)  else .............................................................                                          |   l   ... |
2.5)  Paste 111 in (Sheet6) **a3**.............................                       |   e   .. |

3.1)  Look for string (Sheet1!**L7**) in sheet2(F:F)     ..|   c  3 |
3.2)  if found string (Sheet1!**L7**) copy that row      .....|   y  ..  |
3.3)  Paste in (Sheet6) **a4**                        ...................................   |   c   .. |
3.4)  else            .............................................................                               |   l  ...  |
3.5)  Paste 111 in (Sheet6) **a4**            ............................           |   e   .. |

Then it loops all the way until (sheet1!**L:L**) finds a blank.

Comment: This should be easy. But what have you tried so far. I'll try to write a simple code for you to start with if time permits.

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in cell Sheet6!A2 and copy it down as long as necessary.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!F:F,Sheet1!L5)>0,Sheet1!L5,111)
```